# QGIS Shortest path (point to layer) start point expression in modeller

Tags: qgis, shortest-path

When in QGIS I run processing tool Shortest path (point to layer) ... I am satisfied with the result (below picture red line).
But when I try to run the same tool in QGIS modeller, the result is different (see picture green line)
[image]

**How to define in QGIS modeller shortest path (point to layer) START POINT in expression from point layer (see picture)?**
I have three vector layers:

1. Start point layer (only one point)
2. End point layer (many points)
3. Network layer
   All layers are in the same coordinate system: EPSG:3301

[image]

Comment: Error is in expression:
x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'),'EPSG:3301')) || ',' || y(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'),'EPSG:3301'))

Comment: Error: geom_to_wkt(make_point(x(geometry('layer_start_2672a933_f4f5_45c8_8e78_3c129af475b0')),y(geometry('layer_start_2672a933_f4f5_45c8_8e78_3c129af475b0'))))

Comment: It worked fine for me here [link to answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441280/qgis-shortest-path-layer-to-layer)