# Making shortest path for number of each points with link layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, batch, shortest-path, path, qgis-network-analysis

I want to make shortest path for a number of each points with a link layer in QGIS.

Now, shortest path tool have to click the start point and end point one by one.

But I have 2,000 pairs.

So I want to use batch process.

How can I fill the blank in batch process?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution may be helpful for you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432668/building-the-shortest-route-through-all-points-in-qgis.

Comment: If you have 2000 pairs of points then you'll need to run 1000 processes and produce 1000 layers, I think QGIS could crash. I've done this with 100 pairs and it works fine. This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441280/qgis-shortest-path-layer-to-layer/441616#441616) can be useful.